# Flex 4 - Tooltip always shown on top of every control.

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

How set the properties or in CSS style for Flash builder Tooltip to be always shown in top of every control(Flex Default Controls like textInput,combo,checkbox)?

I need to set layout/position in one place and applied in whole application.

Comment: Please go through link: -- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/03/globally-disabling-tool-tips-using-the-flex-tooltipmanager-class/

Comment: But i need to set the position of displaying Tooltip

Comment: Can you create sample app and post as you have mentioned need to set layout/position........ so that we can understand what exactly you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

The last example on this tutorial shows how to position the tooltip whereever you want using ToolTipManager.createTooltip with x and y specified.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_4.html

Always show tooltips (Flex 3, but may be very similar to Flex 4 impl)
http://flexdevtips.blogspot.ie/2009/08/always-showing-error-tips-validators.html

Hope this helps

B